# Glide update 4.0

Tags: android, android-glide

I am wanting to sign one (.apk) and I get these errors. from what I could investigate is for an update in "GRIDE V4" and my code is obsolete .. And I can not find a solution.
I get those first 3 errors (IMAGE 1)
and then another 2 more (IMAGE 2)
Sorry I have bad English and I am new to programming.
Error 1-2-3 :

```
// load image with callback
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable;
private void glideLoadImageFromUrl(final Context ctx, final String url, final CallbackImageNotif callback) {

    myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Glide.with(ctx).load(url).**asBitmap**().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, **GlideAnimation**<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    callback.onSuccess(resource);
                    mainHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                }


                public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    callback.onFailed(e.getMessage());
                    super.onLoadFailed(**e, errorDrawable**);
                    mainHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
}
```

[image: Error 1-2-3]

ERROR 4-5

```
public static void displayImageOriginal(Context ctx, ImageView img, String url) {
    try {
        Glide.with(ctx).load(url)
                .**crossFade**()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void displayImageThumbnail(Context ctx, ImageView img, String url, float thumb) {
    try {
        Glide.with(ctx).load(url)
                .**crossFade**()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .thumbnail(thumb)
                .into(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

[image: Error 4-5]

Comment: Glide 4 has different ways of doing, many thing are depricated in Glide4 so check glide documentation before using

Comment: For the first error, what you're doing looks really complicated. Do you need to actually do something (like saving or manipulating) with the bitmap or do you just need to load it into an ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

For cross fading/error 4-5, try

```java
  Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .into(imageView);
```

I found this by just looking around in the source code for Glide.
I would also avoid doing the blind try catch for displayImageThumbnail. You'll get callbacks for errors if you call `.listener(RequestListener<TranscodeType>)` in the chain.